# Redirect user after login based on username

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

Using WordPress - I want to check who has just logged in and if they are UsernameX then redirect to PageX, if they are an Administrator then redirect to /wp-admin/ and all others redirect to home_url();

This is my code:

```
function my_login_redirect($redirect_to, $request, $user){
    if(in_array('student',$user->user_login)) {
        return home_url("/students/");
    } else {
        if(in_array('administrator', $user->roles)){
            return home_url("/wp-admin/");
        } else {
            return home_url();
        }
    }
}
add_filter("login_redirect", "my_login_redirect", 10, 3);
```

However it doesn't seem to work - particularly the check against user_login. Is there a better - working - way to do this?

---

**Answer / Correct code** - thanks to @soju:

```
function my_login_redirect($redirect_to, $request, $user){
    if($user->first_name == 'student')) {
        return home_url("/students/");
    } else {
        if(in_array('administrator', $user->roles)){
            return home_url("/wp-admin/");
        } else {
            return home_url();
        }
    }
}
add_filter("login_redirect", "my_login_redirect", 10, 3);
```

This means using the User's first name as $user doesn't contain the username, but if you wanted you could get it using the ID as returned by $user I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line :

```
if(in_array('student',$user->user_login)) {
```

is not correct, `$user->user_login` does not exist and is not an array.

EDIT : http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User

Comment: Thanks soju - do you know where / have a link to the contents of the global $user? I've been searching the codex but couldn't find it.